# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have my code implemented like this and when there is no file how can i raise exception

```
**models.py**

class Template(BaseModel):
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='',
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['xls', 'xlsx'])]
    )
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'Some Model',
        related_name='',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
```

views.py

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def i_view(request):
    data = Model.objects.first()
    response = HttpResponse(
        data.file,
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats
    )
    return response
```

Comment: provide your ``Model``

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Bro i have added model pls take a look

Comment: `Model.objects.first` return `None` since you dont have any records in `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add condition checking if at least one `Model` exists. In `else` add anything you want to happen if there is no `Model`.

```
def i_view(request):
    data = Model.objects.first()
    if data:
        response = HttpResponse(
            data.file,
            content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats'
        )
        return response
    else:
        # here you can do coding if there is no Model object
```